# How can I set up a boolean to call my log analytics workspace?

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I am using Terraform with Azure and I have created a NSG and a log_analytics_workspace.

I want to create a boolean, that when true will create a log_analytics_workspace, the workspace should be placed within the same resource group as the NSG.

Main.tf

```
    resource "azurerm_network_security_group" "example" {
    name                = "NSG-group"
    location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
    resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
    count = var.nsg-log-analytics-workspace == "nsg-log-main" ? 1 : 0 
    
    }
    
    resource "azurerm_log_analytics_workspace" "example" {
      name                = "log-analytics-workspace"
      location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
      resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
      sku                 = "PerGB2018"
      retention_in_days   = 30
    
     nsg_log_category {
     category = log.value
     enabled  = true

     retention_policy {

     enabled = true
     days = 365

    }
```

Variable.tf

```
variable "nsg_log_category" {
  type = list(string) #convert the logs into a list of strings
  default = nsg-main
}
```

Any advice towards what I am missing will be appreciated.

Comment: What would that boolean variable be?

Comment: @MarkoE it would be true. So when the log_analytics workspace is created it is then assigned to the nsg rescource

Comment: I'm asking which variable would that be, not what it's value would be. :)

Comment: @MarkoE is would be nsg_log_category

Comment: I'm sorry, but this makes no sense. Your variable cannot be used that way. What is that supposed to be used with? There is no block in the resource called `nsg_log_category`: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/log_analytics_workspace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I miss the point of your design. Nevertheless if you want to collect the logs of the nsg in the log analytics workspace, you must create an [azurerm_monitor_diagnostic_setting](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/monitor_diagnostic_setting) and insert the **ids** of the nsg and workspace in the resource.